# sending message to chrome extension from a web page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to send message from the console of the random web page to my chrome extension.
chrome.extension.sendMessage doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

According to [the official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#host-page-communication) you should use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) in the sender and [`message`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/message) event listener in the receiver.

Here is an example:

**Your website's page.html**

```
var data = { type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" };
window.postMessage(data, "*");
```

**Content script:** (injected using `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {code:...`)

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window)
        return;

    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
        console.log("Content script received message: " + event.data.text);
    }
});
```

Here `page.html` (which is not a part of the extension) posts messages to itself, which are intercepted and inspected by the content script. The reverse is possible through similar means.

To pass from content script to extension, you will have to use [one of the available message-passing techniques](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/).

It looks complicated and it is somewhat complicated but all this mumbo-jumbo is very secure.

Comment: can I try to insert the code in the Website's html for dispatching event along through the 'chrome.tabs.executeScript()' command?

I tired that and it isn't working... it says,
"Port Error: could not establish connection: receiving end does not exist:

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering how to do this more securely than just window.postMessage. This would definitely have fewer side effects, but still unfortunately could be tampered with by a malicious web page. I'm looking forward to [chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) which will allow a somewhat more secure (hopefully) channel of communication

Comment: @kzahel Content scripts are ran within their own context, so it's isolated from webpage context. Content scripts have access to the DOM (the HTML elements), basically you can attach listeners if you want to pass data between contexts, you can do that via events. Just note there are 3 different contexts: Extension, Custom script, and webpage scripts.

Comment: That first link mentions using `windows.postMessage(...)` so apparently you don't even need a custom myCustomEventDiv, as it were...

Comment: Glad to find this after an hour of searching. Thanks for the writeup!

Comment: Still helping in 2019!

Answer (score 67):

Here's a quote from the latest https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/, It's much simpler to support this kind of feature now, here's how:

> ###Sending messages from web pages
>
> Similar to cross-extension messaging, your app or extension can
> receive and respond to messages from regular web pages. To use this
> feature, you **must** first specify in your `manifest.json` which web
> sites you want to communicate with. For example:
>
> ```
> "externally_connectable": {
>   "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
> }
> ```
>
> This will expose the messaging API to any page which matches the URL
> patterns you specify. The URL pattern must contain at least a
> second-level domain - that is, hostname patterns like "*", "*.com",
> "*.co.uk", and "*.appspot.com" and <all_urls> are prohibited.
> From the web page, use the runtime.sendMessage or runtime.connect APIs
> to send a message to a specific app or extension. For example:
>
> ```
> // The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
> var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";
>
> // Make a simple request:
> chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
>   function(response) {
>     if (!response.success)
>       handleError(url);
>   });
> ```
>
> From your app or extension, you may listen to messages from web pages
> via the runtime.onMessageExternal or runtime.onConnectExternal APIs,
> similar to cross-extension messaging. Only the web page can initiate a
> connection. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
>   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
>     if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
>       return;  // don't allow this web page access
>     if (request.openUrlInEditor)
>       openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
>   });
> ```

Comment: This works for me. However, I have one question. How do people find the ID of their extension? At the moment I just hard code it.

Comment: how to see that message is received by extension, I'm using unpacked extension. I'm currently developing it.

Comment: @user1311069 the extension ID generation mechanism is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21500707/258772

Comment: @pavan I just add an `alert` in the event handler in the extension.

Comment: this would be the best method if it weren't by; 1- you must specify all the externally connactable web sites with at least 2 level domain (its a problem for me) and 2- you must know app/extension id upfront

Comment: Listen to events with `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener()`

Comment: Note that this method does not currently work in Firefox, as of FF 54.  See this for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592605/firefox-webextension-check-if-my-extension-exists

Comment: It won't possible to send message from script from unknown domain as it must defined in manifest.json

Comment: horrible documentation, really

Comment: Does this also work when sending a message from localhost? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It works in localhost, you need to mention it `http://localhost:3000/*` in `externally_connectable`. Also, onMessageExternal works from BGSW not Content Script

Answer (score 12):

So to elaborate, a more concreate example: An issue with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...)` style is that you have to specify the pag you're on as externally_connectable which doesn't take a global wildcard like "https://*/*".  So if you want that ability, you have to use the `postMessage` [style](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) communication.  Capture the message from the window into the `contentscript`, then from the `contentscript`, you can send it elsewhere (if desired, like to the `background.js` etc.)

So in the normal web page, or in injected source that you embed into the normal page, from your `contentscript.js`, send a message like this:

```
window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE_TO_CONTENT_SCRIPT", 
     text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
```

ex, you could add it to a button like this:

```
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
       window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE_TO_CONTENT_SCRIPT", 
                            text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
}, false);
```

Then to capture it in the contentscript.js and "send it on" to the rest of the extension, the only caveat is that you only want to "select" messages that seem to be ones that you care about:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from this window to itself [i.e. not from any iframes]
  if (event.source != window)
    return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE_TO_CONTENT_SCRIPT")) {        
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(event.data); // broadcasts it to rest of extension, or could just broadcast event.data.payload...
  } // else ignore messages seemingly not sent to yourself
}, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can switch to the JS execution context of your content script using the `<page context>` menu at the bottom of a page’s developer JS console, then use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and other `chrome.*` APIs just as you would within the content script.

[image]

Comment: What can be the reason if the execution context switching menu shown in your screenshot does not appear (Chrome v 39.0.2171.95 m, Windows 7)?

Comment: Just for reference - I can access the extension context console by opening the extensions page (`chrome://extensions`) and clicking the *Inspect views: background page* link, so the missing context switching menu is not a big problem really.

Comment: In a recent release, Chrome combined the execution context menu with the frame menu. If your extension has a content script in the page, you should now see it listed under `<top frame>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I only see `<top frame>` when I click on the drop-down, even though the page script is able to communicate with the extension with no problems. But as I can use the background page link from the extensions page, it's just a cosmetic issue.

Comment: @mrts Background script != Content script. There are 3 separate JS execution contexts here: page script (what you see in your console by default), background script (what you see when you inspect the background page and is universal [one instance] for all Chrome tabs), and content script, which runs inside a given tab + given url as defined in manifest.json. If you put `window.foo = 'bar';` in a content script, you won't see it in the background-page-inspection console. afaics it's only viewable via the dropdown that jaredjacobs points out here (which is now under 'top').

Answer (score 4):

In addition to  @hewigovens , I don't have enough points to comment...
I'm explaining @renatoargh and @sbichenko
If sending message from a default web page -

1) the webpage needs to be quoted in the manifest. e.g.:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["http://abcde/abcde/main.aspx*"]
}
```

2) the background.js (background page)
excepts the call with  onMessageExternal  e.g. (calling an extension):

```
var host_name = "com.my_chrome_extension.com";
 chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(host_name, {"run":message});
    sendResponse({"success": "success"});
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it shows how to send messages from chrome extension to web page https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage

Add externally connectible resources in `manifest.json` that matches your web page URL or localhost, if you testing locally.

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

From the web page, use the `runtime.sendMessage` or `runtime.connect` APIs to send a message to a specific app or extension. For example:

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

From your extension, you may listen to messages from web pages via the `runtime.onMessageExternal` or `runtime.onConnectExternal` APIs, similar to `cross-extension` messaging. Only the web page can initiate a connection. Here is an example:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```