# OAuth Application ID for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[Documentation for obtaining an OAuth token](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#client_id) states the 'installed application type' should be set to 'Chrome Application'.

> - Enter the requested branding information, select the Installed
>     application type.

It then instructs the developer to enter their application ID:

> - Select Chrome Application and enter your application
>     ID (same ID displayed in the apps and extensions management page).

However when doing so, it is not possible to edit the application ID prefix of 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/'.

How is it possible to generate a Client ID for a Chrome Extension if the extension is not yet available on the webstore?

Comment: What was unclear about http://stackoverflow.com/a/21500707/938089? It explains what the extension/application ID means, how it can be generated, fixed and uploaded to the CWS.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without using a third-party tool? I'd rather stay within the Google development environment for development and without publishing to the CWS.

Comment: There is no "official" tool to generate the base64-encoded public key from a CRX file (`"key"`). The easiest way for starters is to get this string is through the CRX Viewer (the demo at https://robwu.nl/crxviewer is fully offline). The logic of creating this string is available at https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/blob/504f17520deb639f66c3ae60c2d70167243205ae/src/lib/crx-to-zip.js#L13-L36. It's as "simple" as cutting the public key (binary) blob from the CRX file, then base64-encoding it.

Comment: I've added a detailed answer with an alternative method to your original question, without any "third-party" tools (except for the well-established OpenSSL program). Since your two questions were pretty much identical, I've marked this one as a duplicate of the previous one. If anything is unclear or incomplete, feel free to comment on the other question. In the future, please don't post duplicate questions. If you feel that a question was incorrectly closed, just flag the question or comment with `@RobW` (or whoever closed the question) and ask for the question to be re-opened.