# Packaging Chrome extension with a predefined key

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm testing extension update. I'd like to test it with the extension from the store. I'm able to load the extension with the desired key (defined through `manifest.json`) through `chrome://extensions` *Load unpacked extension*, but as soon as I pack it the key changes - both when using the `my_extension.pem` and without it.

Is it possible to pack an extension with the same key it has in the Chrome Web Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension ID is directly calculated from [`"key"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key), which in turn is based on the `.pem` file that is used for packaging the extension.

For development, you **can** set your extension ID to any arbitrary value you want, provided that you've got the `key` for that extension ID. However, you **cannot** *package* an extension with an arbitrary extension ID, *unless* you've got the `.pem` file from which the `key` can be derived.

If you did not include a file called `key.pem` when you uploaded your extension to the Chrome Web Store for the first time, then you **cannot** create a CRX file with the given extension ID, because the `.pem` file will then only be known by the Chrome Web Store (the `.pem` file is auto-generated by the CWS if omitted).

However, you **can** load an unpacked extension with your preferred extensionID by setting the `"key"` in the manifest file, see [How to change chrome packaged app id Or Why do we need key field in the manifest.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21500707) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, very elaborate and descriptive :)