# Receiving the Chrome API (chrome.runtime) within Selenium test

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I successfully got Selenium tests to work with my Chrome extension. But still I have an issue where the ID of the extension should be received through the Chrome API.

**Why do I need that?**
Since the project is within Git I want to ensure that my code buddy can run the tests without configuring much. Everything works fine BUT the ID for the extension differs from every machine.

My ID is:

> chrome-extension://**dafanlbggefkfnbekjceijjhgcancpik**/html/options.html

What do I need? To receive this ID dynamically I need access to `chrome.runtime.id`. Which is not trivial since the Chrome API is not accessible for me within my Selenium test code.

```
var extensionID = chrome.runtime.id;
var urlToOptionsPage = 'chrome-extension://'+ extensionID +'/html/options.html';
```

That's what I actually want to achieve so my Selenium tests can open the proper locale extension URL.

Does anybody have a clue what I need to do within the `manifest.json` or within Selenium configs or another workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromedriver extension id does not match key in manifest.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899725/chromedriver-extension-id-does-not-match-key-in-manifest-json)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution there and my case is not exactly similar to those

Comment: I have the same problem using the "Load unpacked extension…" button in the Extensions window.  Some consolation: Upon relaunch, Chrome 58 reloads my unpacked extension with the same identifier.