# Disable update of specific chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

With recent news of adblock being sold to some unknown company, first thing i want to do is disable any possible update for that extension.

I've found number of questions but they are outdated. So chrome pros please tell **how do we disable a specific plugin?** and please take into consideration that there are many instances which synchronize it is important that the **change gets synchronized to other computers**, if it is not how do we do that?.

And a secondary question : **where do we find sources of already installed extension**? so that we could later pack and run it?

Comment: Voting to move to superuser.com. As for AdBlock, I simply moved to uBlock a long time ago and never looked back.

Comment: Well this is more development question thus i posted here expecting extension devs to quickly give an answer... adblock is just an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome does not offer a way of disabling an update for a specific extension.

If you want to make sure that you run some specific version of an extension, you could try any of the following options:

### Read-only extension folder

Go to the directory containing the extension, and mark the directory as read-only. To find that directory, visit `chrome://version` and look at the path at "Profile Path". The extension will then be at `[value of Profile path]/Extensions/[32-character extension id]`.

### Download the source code

Download the source code of the extension, and load it as an unpacked extension (or upload it to the Chrome Web store, and then install it).
There are several ways to get the source code (including just copying it from the directory as I mentioned at the previous step).

If you want to download a Chrome extension without installing it (e.g. because the new version contains unwanted "features" that you want to remove), then you could use my [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) to download the code.

Some extensions expect to be run with a specific extension ID. You can forge this extension ID if you load the extension in unpacked mode (but you cannot upload the extension to the CWS if you do that). For instructions on fixing the extension ID, see [How to change chrome packaged app id Or Why do we need key field in the manifest.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest/21500707#21500707).