# Webpack 2.x, does __webpack_public_path__ still work?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, webpack, typescript2.0, webpack-2

I have a chrome extension with unstable, stable and nightly versions being released, and I need to be able to dynamically set the public path to the extension resources. I've been trying to add it in many ways, by a js entry directly into the webpack.config.js, importing from my ts entries, putting directly in the ts files..

I just want __webpack_public_path__ to be changed globally to something which I can't count on to always be the same between builds.

I have tried like this:

```
__webpack_public_path__ = chrome.extension.getURL("");
var __webpack_public_path__ = chrome.extension.getURL("");
let __webpack_public_path__ = chrome.extension.getURL("");
window.__webpack_public_path__ = chrome.extension.getURL("");
```

Does anyone know if this has changed since Webpack 2.x?

### Update!

This is my webpack.config.development.js

```
var path = require('path');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
var RawLoader = require('raw-loader');
var CssLoader = require('css-loader');
var TextLoader = require('text-loader');
var VendorChunkPlugin = require('webpack-vendor-chunk-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ngtools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var webpack_devtool = "source-map";
var webpack_name = "development";
var webpack_build_title = "Webpack Development Build";
var webpack_app_dir = "app";
var webpack_build_dir = "build";
var webpack_public_path = ""

module.exports = [
    {
        name: webpack_name,
        devtool: webpack_devtool,
        context: path.join(__dirname, webpack_app_dir),
        entry: {
            "webpack-setups": './webpack-setups.js',
            "fa": "font-awesome-webpack2!./font-awesome.config.js",
            "content_script": './hp.my.content_script.com_console.ts',
            "content_script2": './hp.my.content_script2.ts',
            "popup": './popup.ts',
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, webpack_build_dir),
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            publicPath: webpack_public_path
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "app"),
                "node_modules",
                "modded_node_modules"
            ],
            extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js", ".ts"]
        },
        plugins: [
            function () {
                this.plugin('watch-run', function (watching, callback) {
                    console.log('Watch triggered! Begin compile at ' + new Date());
                    callback();
                });
                this.plugin('done', function () {
                    console.log('Finished compile at ' + new Date());
                });
            },
            new WebpackNotifierPlugin({ title: webpack_build_title })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: ["ts-loader"]
                },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style", "css"] },
                { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/, use: "url" },
                { test: /\.html/, use: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]' },
                { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
                { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
            ]
        }
    }
];
```

Contents of webpack-setups.js

```
__webpack_public_path__ = chrome.extension.getURL("");
```

package.json snippet:

```
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"webpack-notifier": "^1.4.1",
"webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.4.3",
"webpack-vendor-chunk-plugin": "^1.0.0",
```

Comment: Please post your configuration and version of webpack@2.1.0-beta

Comment: @SeanLarkin It's all there. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Webpack is not letting me dynamically set public path, I resolved this by making the chrome extension ID more predictable, using the below stackoverflow answer (which by the way features other varied ways to go about this).

[How to change chrome packaged app id Or Why do we need key field in the manifest.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest)

> The ID is derived from the .pem file that was created the first time
>   you (or the Chrome Web Store) packed the extension in a .crx file.
>   When you load an extension in "unpacked mode", an ID is automatically
>   generated in an unpredictable way. The only way to control the
>   extension ID during development is by setting the "key" field in the
>   manifest file, as the documentation suggests.
>
> [... more info on getting the key in source url]

And the following [google support page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#copy_key).

> Copy key to your manifest
>   When you register your application in the
>   Google OAuth console, you'll provide your application's ID, which will
>   be checked during token requests. Therefore it's important to have a
>   consistent application ID during development.
>
> To keep your application ID constant, you need to copy the key in the
>   installed manifest.json to your source manifest. It's not the most
>   graceful task, but here's how it goes:
>
> Go to your user data directory. Example on MacOs:
>   ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions List
>   the installed apps and extensions and match your app ID on the apps
>   and extensions management page to the same ID here. Go to the
>   installed app directory (this will be a version within the app ID).
>   Open the installed manifest.json (pico is a quick way to open the
>   file). Copy the "key" in the installed manifest.json and paste it into
>   your app's source manifest file.