# Cannot run my chrome extension in other broswer/machine except mine : some mismatch in unpacked distribution?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Sorry for my poor English, i hope you can understand the issue.

I'm new to  chrome extension development,and for sure in my code there are a lot of 
thing to change or optimize; 
anyway  i've written a simple code that,  (seems) works at least from my chrome.

The code clicks a button every X minutes in specific page, then wait and parse the result in page.

I've :

- a content script (loaded from manifest.json) which "inject" some button and text Input box in page,   so user can sets some "filter params" before click a "start button"; the start button then sendMessage()  to background.js to set Alarm Event for the click ;
- an eventPage (which is set persistent true in actually ) which handle the request from tabs  and set a countdown alarm for each tab; when X min are passed fire a message to the interested tab;

I also have a popup.html e popup.js not important here (i think).

I've to distribuite this extension manually, so i would distribuite a zip that user can load with "developer mode ".

*Now the issue is: why the code was working only on my Chrome ? *

I've tested with others 2-3 laptop with Chrome, the background script is loaded (i can see the background page printint console log)

**but in webpage the contents.js seems no way executed .**

In my chrome works well: i can see in console some initial output (i print the name of dir extension to check) and
the dynamic created element (button,input box ect.)  in page.

And all is working, i can fire the start button and receive results of parsing.

During the development i've never run the extension on other machine. Yesterday i've succssfully tested on 2-3 laptop.. then i made only few change but nothing serious.

Today i can run only in my chrome.

In other pc nothing, neither the simple console.log output first line of script.

I can read in console log :
"Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."
*but this also in my working istance in my laptop chrome .*

The zip file  is the same and the extraction is good, in fact i can actually load the extension and i see the background page debug console.log() sentences

In some case, in laptop where it dosen't work, i've received a message relative jQuery and the fact that chrome.runtime.sendMessage() is not defined; and it points to code in webpage, not mine.

I've see that in webpage code there is something like:

```
 var extid = "mcmhdskbnejjjdjsdkksmeadjaibo";
          var extVer = "1.5";
          var extStatus = 0;
   $(document).ready(function () { 
///...
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extid, {message: "version"},
                  function (reply) {
                      if (reply) {
                          if (reply.version) {
                              if (reply.version == extVer) {
                                  if (reply.gminfo != 'OK') {
                                      extStatus = 1; /// ...
```

Seems that chrome.runtime  is undefined, and the webpage can't call the sendMessage().
EDIT: this undefined occurs only when my extension is loaded

Maybe there is some conflict when i load my extension? But in my chrome browser works...

Can some expert indicate in where direction i've to investigate?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

My Manifest.json :

```
  {"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "myAlarm",
  "description": "This extension alerts.",
  "version": "0.1",
   "permissions": [
   "alarms",
   "system.cpu",
   "storage",
   "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
   "https://www.mytargetsite.com/subUrl/"
     ],

   "web_accessible_resources": [
   "icon.png",
   "vanillaSelectBox.css"],

    "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["https://www.mytargetsite.com/subUrl/"],
     "css": ["vanillaSelectBox.css"],
     "js": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js","vanillaSelectBox.js","taffy-min.js","content.js"],
     "run_at": "document_end"
     }
      ],

    "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": true
     },

     "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },

   "icons": {
     ....
      }
      }
```

My contents,js (stripped):

```
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
            function(request, sender) {
          // here i parse message "time'up" from background js    
              });

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var pt=chrome.runtime.getURL('filterOff.wav'); 
      var p=pt.split("/");

      console.log("[myAlarm v0.1] started" );
      console.log("[myAlarm v0.1] folder : ("+p[2]+")");
       // here i start an active wait for the presence in page of button with ID= btntarget_id
      waitForElementToDisplay("#btntarget_id", 500); //when function find button then create and add button and input text to webpage
         });
```

My eventPage.js :

```
            var curr_alarms =[];
             chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender)
              {   /// here receive start countdown message from content.js and set alarm  ...
               }


            chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
              /// here i manage each alarm for each tab
              });

              chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabid, removed) { 
                //  ...
             });

            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function
             (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
               //
               });
```

edit :  in browser where it dosen't work i can read also :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mytargetsite.com/suburl/grid.php' (redirected from 'https://mytargetsite.com/suburl/grid.php') from origin 'https://mytargetsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The fact that the declared content script runs or not, should be verified by inspecting in devtools => sources sub-tab => content scripts sub-sub-tab. If it really doesn't run, there can be just two explanations: the URL is different (for example not `https`) or extensions are blocked by their domain admin via runtime_blocked_hosts which you can see in `chrome://policy`.
2. Your development mode extension's id will be different on a different machine unless you [pin it by adding a "key"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21500707) in manifest.json
3. To use `chrome.runtime` to send messages to your extension from a webpage code (not from a content script!) your extension's manifest should declare ["externally_connectable"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) and use a different event onMessageExternal, see also [sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).
4. The CORS error may be irrelevant to your code (you can investigate the source of the error by expanding the error's call stack in devtools console).

Comment: 1- You're right ! I've spent some hours and then discovered than a 302 redirect url did some mismatch in loading !  So this is the real issue.

2- I catch the moment :  i'm a bit confused...  adding key is stricly need to distribuite "manually" my unpacked extension ? (i mean, i would send a zip file to users; then they extract and load.. is it ok ? or i'm missing something?)