# How to load an unpacked chrome extension on a new Chrome Profile?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am developing an unpacked local chrome extension with manifest version 2 that uses the [chrome.identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/) which currently works on my main [Chrome Profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824), and I'd also like to install it on my second Chrome Profile.

However, i am getting this error only on the Second Profile: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'internal server error`, which normally means that the 'key' field in manifest.json is not set correctly (thrown by chrome.identity API).
The thing is, i've followed the exact same [steps](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/key/) on this secondary profile as I did on my main profile, but it only gives the error on the secondary profile:

- Dragged the .crx file over to the `chrome://extensions` page.
- Typed `chrome://version` in the search bar and navigated to the "Profile Path" listed there.
- Copied the "key" field in manifest.json
- Removed the extension installed from the .crx
- Pasted the "key" into my extension folder
- Selected "Load Unpacked".

What I've also tried:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest/21500707#21500707)
  and [this answer](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_identity/#copy_key), but it didn't solve my problem.
- Removing the existing extension from the main profile before installing it on the new one, but that didn't work either.

Additional info:

- When loading the extensions, their extension IDs are the same, which I believe is expected since they come from the same .crx file.
- Both keys are also the same, which I'm not sure is expected behavior since each profile has its own path where the extension folder shows up when I install the .crx file. (maybe having two extensions with the same key is giving some kind of conflict even though they are on different profiles?)
- I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: If the id is identical to the extension in the first profile then you must have a `pem` file in the same directory when you create crx so just move it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the issue: the new profile wasn't registered as a trusted tester on Google Cloud.

**Steps to fix:**

1. Go to [Google Cloud OAuth consent
   screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent).
2. In "Test Users" section, add the e-mail for the new Chrome Profile.