# Google not allowing to upload manifest v2 plugin (trying to upgrade plugin not a new upload)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

As per google documentation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/ V2 versions are allowed till 2024 to upgrade (we are not uploading new extension, upgrading existing version with some bug fixes) but after bug fixing when we tried to upgrade plugin we are getting error to update extension to V3 (manifest).

Can someone provide guidance on how to upload V2 extension and skip V3 error.

I tried to upgrade extension to V3 also but service worker creating problem in DOM as its not having access to DOM so we wanted to continue with V2 only for now by making fixes in existing extension.

Comment: You can ignore that error.

Comment: there is no option to ignore

Comment: If the error is "Manifest version 2 is deprecated, and support will be removed in 2023", you can ignore it.

If not, please post what the error is.

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest this also but not working

Comment: no, error is not like that, when i tried to upgrade plugin i received message as "There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again. * key field is not allowed in manifest." then i tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest these steps but error is " you can no longer publish V2 Extension try converting your Extension to V3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue we contacted google team and what we observed is:-

To update the package steps we folllowed were incorrect, to upload package you have to click the "upload new package" button on the package page.

support link for google
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/one_stop_support

Comment: "To update the package steps we folllowed were incorrect." 

What steps were you following? If you were following the documentation on developer.chrome.com, please file a bug on the project's GH repo: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com.