# Window.postMessage - Two pages, same URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

I'm using

```
window.postMessage({message: "Hello !"}, url);
```

to send a message from a Chrome Extension (i don't know if this is relevant) to a specific page in a window with multiples opened pages. I noticed that sometimes i have **TWO** pages with the **same URL**.

I have a **simple question**:

How can i be sure to which page is postMessage sending the message ?

I want to send the message to only one tab. Can i use anything else apart from the url to identify the it?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: We need to know why you are sending a `postMessage` message. Are you trying to talk with the page's own scripts? If yes, do you control that page, i.e. can you modify it to respond to another event?

Comment: I'm using "postMessage" to send a message from my Extension to an external website script. Did i answer your question ?

Comment: Can you modify the external website script, if needed? To react to another event.

Comment: Yes, i can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you said you can modify the remote website's code, and I don't see how to fix the `postMessage` solution, here are a couple of alternatives. **I would love to know if there is a way to fix the `postMessage` approach, as it is the recommended one from the docs!**

First off, you will need to coordinate your scripts from a central background page, which can keep track of open tabs.

### Custom DOM events

This is an old recommendation from Chrome docs, that was replaced with `window.postMessage` example. It is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11431812/934239) (disregard the old `chrome.extension.connect` API) and consists of firing a custom event in shared DOM.

So, a sample architecture would be a background page deciding which tab to post message to, and sending that tab a message via `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, to which your content script listens with `chrome.runtime.onMessage`. The tab's content script can then communicate with the page using the above custom event technique.

One possible approach to keeping tack of tabs: have the `tabs` permission to be able to enumerate all open tabs with the [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). Your background page can then decide which tab to message based on URL.

Another possible approach, to eliminate need for the scary `tabs` permission, is to have your content scripts report to the background page with `chrome.runtime.connect` as soon as they are initialized. The background page then can keep track of all active instances of your script and therefore decide which tab to message.

### Webpage connecting to your extension

This is a "modern" way of doing communication with one exact extension.

It is described in the Chrome docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage). You can define your extension as externally connectable from your webpage, and your webpage initiates a port connection with your background script.

Then, as above, you can track live ports and use them for communication, cutting out the content script middleman.

Comment: Oh ! I didn't notice your answer ! I will try it as soon as possible and let you know if it worked :) I just didn't understand what you are referring to in the bold sentence \